# Powershell scripting itself or with another instance without closing it

Tags: powershell, path

PowerISE(script) that runs a new instance or in itself and execute code inline without exiting. I know this is not possible cause "security reasons" (this is argumented by Microsoft) and the best you can do is 'Read-Host', which only "PAUSE" until Enter, unexpectedly I found the solution while writing this post via -NoNewWindow cmdlet in the script, but i was trying another way before i got it and curiosly i kept the doubt, and i was wondering if it can be possible. **Can i save the buffering of the script in some type of variable or as an object (in real life like holding ctrl+c) and then paste it right click on powershell?**

Be patient with me in posting stuff i'm new and i hope i'm posting this as it should be and if not tell me so i can make it properly.

This is my simple code (solution):

`#path cd C:\wamp64\www Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" Start-Process powershell.exe -NoNewWindow`

My output idea is like:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All right reserved.

PS C:\Users\x> cd C:\wamp64\www
PS C:\wamp64\www>Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
```

And yes this is because the laziness of opening some software and then the path and writing stuff as parameters etc. XD

The main source problem was this, every time i open git-bash it hits home directory i want only one line to get to project root instead of cd .. or cd  and automatically aply a git status. So any suggests about this also counts.

I have tried Read-Host cmdlet, or even a cmd opening a powershell with a PAUSE. I couldn't find information even in microsoft about handlerEvents for bufferring or how to retrieve the history (alias -h). A few answers lead me here on stackover flow regarding Read-Host, another like solvetic.com suggest to change registry keys to prevent closing powershell

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\powershell.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\ "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" –noExit \ “& \\ “%1\\ """
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command]
@="\ “C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe\ “ –NoExit \ “-Command" "if ( ( Get-ExecutionPolicy ) –ne ‘AllSigned’) { Set-ExecutionPolicy –Scope Process Bypass }; & \\ "%1" \\ “""

which i dont want to touch this keys BTW.

Comment: Doesn't look like a `git` question

Comment: certainly it wasn't, but my question was born  because what i expalined, i better untagged the git tag.

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is. What exactly is it you can't do, and where can I find the relevant Microsoft "security reasons" claim somewhere?